# Understanding numpy formatting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have been reading the numpy array formatting [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays) and I cannot achieve what I want to do.

Given a matrix array where each column represents a different field, I want to format each column as integer or double depending on the data that that column represents.

Before marking this as duplicate, consider that I do not want to have this `[(), (), (), ..., ()]`, I want this `[[], [], [], ..., []]` type of structure, exactly as it comes but with different types per column.

See my attempts below.

```
from numpy import array, intc, double

bus_format_str1 = [(" ", intc),
                  ("BUS_TYPE", intc),
                  ("PD", double),
                  ("QD", double),
                  ("GS", double),
                  ("BS", double),
                  ("BUS_AREA", intc),
                  ("VM", double),
                  ("VA", double),
                  ("BASE_KV", double),
                  ("ZONE", intc),
                  ("VMAX", double),
                  ("VMIN", double)]


bus_format_str2 = "|i8, i8, f8, f8, f8, f8, f8, f8, f8, i8, f8, f8"

# original array    
Bus = array([[1, 1, 97.6, 44.2, 0, 0, 2, 1.0393836, -13.536602, 345, 1, 1.06, 0.94],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1.0484941, -9.7852666, 345, 1, 1.06, 0.94],
       [3, 1, 322, 2.4, 0, 0, 2, 1.0307077, -12.276384, 345, 1, 1.06, 0.94]])

print(Bus)

# Attempts to apply the format
Bus_format1 = array(Bus, dtype=bus_format_str1)
Bus_format2 = array(Bus, dtype=bus_format_str2)

print(Bus_format1)
print(Bus_format2)
```

Both format strings produce structures that have nothing to do with the original.

So, how do I apply the mentioned independent format per column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What, exactly, is the source of `Bus`?  When I cut and paste your string

```
In [50]: Bus = array([[1, 1, 97.6, 44.2, 0, 0, 2, 1.0393836, -13.536602, 345, 1, 1.06, 0.94],
```

...345, 1, 1.06, 0.94]])

I get an array that is all floats:

```
In [51]: Bus
Out[51]: 
array([[   1.       ,    1.       ,   97.6      ,   44.2      ,
           0.       ,    0.       ,    2.       ,    1.0393836,
         -13.536602 ,  345.       ,    1.       ,    1.06     ,    ....   ]])
```

`Bus_format2 = array(Bus, dtype=bus_format_str2)` really messes things up, replicating each element of `Bus` over the fields in the dtype:

```
array([[(1L, 1L, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1L, 1.0, 1.0),
    (1L, 1L, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1L, 1.0, 1.0),
    ....
```

Notice the inner `()`. You don't want `[(), (), (), ..., ()]`, but you also want `different types per column`.  You can't have it both ways.  If the array is structured, with different types per column, `numpy` will display it with the `[()]` form.  The `[[]]` is only for arrays with the same type all around.

You may need to reread the documentation about dtypes and structured arrays.

But maybe you aren't concerned about the numpy representation of the data, but about the print style.  But why is that important?  Are you writing to a file that demands a particular style? Writing to share with someone else, or for publication?

---

A structured array with your data, and different types per column can be constructed with:

Start with a list of lists:

```
In [66]: Bus = [[1, 1, 97.6, 44.2, 0, 0, 2, 1.0393836, -13.536602, 345, 1, 1.06, 0.94],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1.0484941, -9.7852666, 345, 1, 1.06, 0.94],
       [3, 1, 322, 2.4, 0, 0, 2, 1.0307077, -12.276384, 345, 1, 1.06, 0.94]]
```

A dtype with 13 fields (matching the length of the sublists)

```
In [67]: dt='i,i,f,f,i,i,i,f,f,i,i,f,f'
```

conversion to tuples is required for structured array input:

```
In [68]: A=np.array([tuple(x) for x in Bus],dtype=dt)
```

The result isn't particularly legible, but that's because we have 13 columns, some of which are floats:

```
In [69]: A
Out[69]: 
array([ (1, 1, 97.5999984741211, 44.20000076293945, 0, 0, 2, 1.0393836498260498, -13.536602020263672, 345, 1, 1.059999942779541, 0.9399999976158142),
       (2, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 2, 1.0484941005706787, -9.785266876220703, 345, 1, 1.059999942779541, 0.9399999976158142),
       (3, 1, 322.0, 2.4000000953674316, 0, 0, 2, 1.0307077169418335, -12.276384353637695, 345, 1, 1.059999942779541, 0.9399999976158142)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4'), ('f6', '<i4'), ('f7', '<f4'), ('f8', '<f4'), ('f9', '<i4'), ('f10', '<i4'), ('f11', '<f4'), ('f12', '<f4')])
```

Use `repr` if you want to see the dtype along with the data: `print(repr(A))`.  That's a good idea when asking questions about structured arrays.

Comment: Aha, then it is compulsory to have the rows converted to tuples which are then formatted all together.

Comment: The format is important because the integer fields are used as indices for other numpy arrays, that is my main concern.